# Is Stumbling Feint a misprint?

Tags: monk, multi-classing, pathfinder-2e, unarmed-combat

Luce Bri is a human fighter, who decided to take the [Martial Artist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=67) archetype dedication.

This means Luce doesn't have access to Flurry of Blows, as it's only available if Luce instead takes the Monk multiclass dedication.

That said, [Stumbling Feint](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1744&ArchLevel=8) specifies:

> When you use Flurry of Blows, you can attempt a check to Feint as a free action just before the first Strike.

And gives some additional benefits as part of that feint to both attacks from Flurry of Blows.

How can Luce ever benefit from this archetype feat, unless Luce also multiclasses Monk to get access to Flurry of Blows? Is this just an oversight from Paizo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As currently written, it is likely a misprint, as the only way to get Flurry of Blows is to multiclass monk; hopefully Paizo will publish some sort of errata. Theoretically one could start Monk and still get this benefit without multiclassing monk, but since Luce is a fighter, she's a bit out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Stumbling Feint only works with Flurry of Blows, so it won't be usable by any character who doesn't have that class feature. Bear in mind, the archetype could be applied to a character who is a monk, so it's not impossible to have Flurry of Blows and Stumbling Feint.

It's hard to say if it's a bug or a feature without knowing author intent. Perhaps the author intended exactly this, or perhaps an earlier form of the archetype gave Flurry of Blows, or could only be applied to a Monk, or maybe it's just future-proofed, and waiting for you to gain Flurry of Blows another way. There are plenty of other feats in the archetype that still work for non-monk Martial Artists.